# Generic Type Arguments Issue

Tags: c#

Basically, I've been searching the internet for a while to find out why I have this problem but I can't find the answer. Can someone please help me with the solution?
I have heard that it has something to do with the namespaces but I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong.

The error is with me trying to create a new linked list and it comes up with the requires type 1 arguement with "LinkedList" and "List".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace LinkedList2
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
    }

    public class List
    {
        private Node head;
        public void AddData(int data)
        {
            Node node = new Node();
            while (node != null)
            {
                System.Console.Write(node.data);
                System.Console.Write(" -> ");
                node = node.next;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            LinkedList List1 = new List(); 
         }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments  Soft153Assignment   C:\Users\Casey\Desktop\University Assignments\Soft153Assignment\Soft153Assignment\Program.cs    53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments  Soft153Assignment   C:\Users\Casey\Desktop\University Assignments\Soft153Assignment\Soft153Assignment\Program.cs    53

Comment: `LinkedList List1 = new List()` should be `List List1 = new List()`. Your *namespace* is `LinkedList2` (think of namespaces like directories on your computer), but your *class* is `List` (think of it as *files*). You must declare your variable `List1` as a type, not a namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` is a class name built-in the `.NET` framework under the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. If you look at the top of your code, you're `using System.Collections.Generic` which means that "your" `public class List` conflicts with the one in the `.NET` framework

What you can do is rename "your" `List` or use the `.NET` built-in classes such as `LinkedList` and `List` since those can pretty much do what you want a specific collections class to do.

you could make your code look something like this... if you're required to use 'List` as the name of your class.

```
namespace LinkedList2
{
    public class Node
    {
        //...
    }
    public class List
    {
        //...
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List List1 = new List();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could do that but for this assignment I am not allowed to use built-in functions.

Comment: you could rename it to `MyList` since it's often leads to confusion when there are classes with the same name from different namespaces.

Comment: If you're required to name it as `List` then you could move the `class Program` inside your `namespace LinkedList2`

Comment: I editted my answer with a code, you could make it look like that

Comment: Thank you very much Paolo, that has sorted my issue out and there is no longer an error. I am very thankful for this!

Comment: you should try reading a book or something to better understand the `.NET` framework. Good luck! :)

Comment: I probably will starting next month. But once again, thank you!